# Display String array in spring MVC

Tags: arrays, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to display string array in JSP page.

I have got a test String array in my controller set this to my registration model

```
String[] test={"ab","cb","sc","ad"};
registration.setTestArray(test);
```

Now I am trying to display it in jsp Its working fine if I do like this

```
<tr>
        <c:forEach var="arr" items="${registration.testArray}">
            <td>${arr} </td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
```

But my problem is I want to display only some of the values from this array like 2nd and 4th index of this array.

I tried like

```
<tr>
        <c:forEach var="arr" items="${registration.testArray}">
            <td>${arr[2]} </td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
```

but its throwing an error. This is just a test in my actual project I have long array of array from which I have to display some selected values.

I am thinking of doing this by first process my required values in controller and then display it in jsp. But I am not sure is this the best method. It would be great help if someone suggest me the better way.

Comment: You have a logical condition to display the values? If you want to hard code the position in the array there's no need to loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you get these "selected values". You can:

- `${registration.testArray[2]}`
- you can loop using a specific `step` of the [`c:forEach` tag](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html)
- you can loop everything and check `<c:if test="${selectedValues.contains(arrItem)}`

Comment: Thanks Sergio Michels and Thanks Bozho. It really helped me